# Handling mouse events using Microsoft Test Management and the Test Runner

Tags: .net, wpf, automation, test-runner, microsoft-test-manager

In toying around with test automation using MS Test Manager with a WPF application, I noticed that while recording the tool does not necessarily record user input in the form of mouse clicks and hovers, but by recording actions dependent on the context of is being acted upon.

Some examples, for clarity:
1.) Clicking on a button will record: "Click 'button1' button".
2.) Clicking on a combobox will record: "Click 'cboBox1' combo box".
     ...followed by "Select 'blah' in 'cboBox1' combo box".
3.) Clicking on a slider will record: "Set position '2' in 'slider1' slider".

These are fine for bread an butter cases, but if the UI depends on such events as MouseEnter/MouseHover etc, it seems that automation is not possible.

Is it possible to automate a control that depends on, for instance, the position of the mouse? Or is this outside the context of the capabilities of the Test Runner?